# Lodash: _.has check for keys returning false

Tags: javascript, object, key, lodash

I have this object:

`values = {page: "0", length: "12"}`

I want to check if the keys have `page` and `length` so I came up with this solution using `Lodash`:

`has(values, 'page') && has(values, 'length')`

This return true as expected but I wanted to use a more shorthand approach and tried:

`has(values, ['page', 'length]')` but this returns false. Any idea why?

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has

`Lodash` has an example where this returns true:

```
var object = { 'a': { 'b': 2 } };

_.has(object, 'a');
// => true

_.has(object, 'a.b');
// => true

_.has(object, ['a', 'b']);
// => true
```

Is there a more elegant way to check for the keys in my object or should I just keep my solution the way it is: `has(values, 'page') && has(values, 'length')`?

Comment: `_.has(object, path)` `<-` did you read the word `path`? basically, lodash will traverse the object using that path.

Comment: also, it's possible that the `"0"` value is treated as `false` instead of the number 0. Finally, your value for length is also being treated like a string, which could cause subtle casting problems as well

Comment: Ah i get it thanks .. Yea unfortunately I'm getting these values from the backend so I need to parse the string values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_.has(object, path)` `<-` did you read the word path? basically, **lodash** will traverse the object using that path.

I think you can use vanilla javascript for doing that:

```js
let values = { page: "0", length: "12" },
    keys = Object.keys(values),
    result = ['page', 'length'].every(k => keys.includes(k));
    
console.log(result);
```

Using **lodash**:

```js
let values = { page: "0", length: "12" },
    keys = _.keys(values),
    result = _.every(['page', 'length'], k => _.includes(keys, k));
        
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.at()` to pluck the values from the object, and than compare the result's length with the original number of keys:

```js
var values = {page: "0", length: "12"}

const hasKeys = (obj, keys) => _.eq(_.at(obj, keys).length, keys.length);

console.log(hasKeys(values, ['page', 'length']));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```